# Why would veteran wizards prefer to summon their wand?

Tags: magic

Unlike the underlings from Hogwarts, those who possess high affinity and proficiency in the art of magic prefer to summon their wand in public. A summoning spell requires a significant amount of concentration and knowledge of incantation spells. However, legend has it that a skilled wizard can call upon any inanimate object, regardless of size, without reciting magical words. Mass and quality depends largely on the wizard's ability to form a mental image in the mind.

The highest form of summoning related spell is the reversal, also known as the sealing spell, which is roughly ten times as difficult as performing a normal summoning, and takes a heavy toll on the user's stamina and focus. The summoning spell is a form of channeling spell, meaning it is not instantaneous and success varies proportionately with time.

**Why would a highly skilled wizard prefer to use a summoning spell to call upon a puny wand, regardless of situation, every time?**

Comment: The wand is said to be an amplifier. it's the same reason muggles call upon their calculators to do math, no matter how mathematically adept they may be

Comment: Because they *can*, and they're all insufferable show-offs.

Comment: Perhaps out of habit or a need to have a crutch of sorts. Some people rely on tools to help them when they aren't needed people they don't have enough faith in their own abilities.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how the paragraph starting "The highest form of summoning spell..." has any bearing on the question and I don't understand how "the reversal" or "sealing spell" is any different than any other summoning spell. It's not described, just said to be difficult for some reason?

Comment: @ErinThursby: before a wizard can summon an object, that particular object had to be prepared in advance meaning to seal it somewhere else because even magic obey the conservation of mass in my world.

Comment: How is that different from normal summoning? If that's the rule for everything? By seal do you mean store extra-dimensionally?

Comment: @Erin Thursdy: technically yes you can put it this way, but no time will pass in this dimension.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. For sure you should edit it. Nobody's putting a wand in that one. you'd want to keep your wand close. I'd put emergency rations in there.

Answer (score 4):

Magic wands are actually batteries. In fact, the design is a magically enchanted Volta battery. There are two main design trends for recharge technology:

- Left to recharge by exposure to light of the appropriate frequency
- Recharged by plugging them to a pyramidal battery, which is often too big and cumbersome to summon.

Once summoned by the wizard the wand provides extra energy for stronger spells. Saying that the wand is an amplifier is just to mislead the unincited.

It should be noted that the wand could be constructed for private use, meaning that it could be designed to be used by only the wizard who created it. This also allows optimizing the energy output for ease of use.

Another thing to notice is that Wizards prefer to scale up the design to increase the capacity of the wand. In fact, they have a hip word for a scaled up wand, they call it a "staff".

Comment: @user6760 Right, I had not thought of that. Although my answer is based on a description I did read on some old "magic" book (magic as occultism not as in illusionism), I distinctively remember going "pff, that's a battery". Trying to find it online I found something about recharging in some website that sells "magic" wands. So, I went with that.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Theraot's excellent answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/56111/why-would-veteran-wizards-prefer-to-summon-their-wand#56117), the wand may be an encumbrance on trips or journeys.  A wizard cannot lose his wand by natural effects such as displacement or by intervening natural barriers, as there is a magical connection which the sorcerer can feel, however such a sense may be diminished with distance.

When the wand, or as in Theraot's answer, the staff, is summoned it can be brought into a situation where getting it there in the first place would cause a burden on the wizard or present the risk of dropping, ensnaring, unhanding of the object (into the hands of a captor) or revealing the presence of the wizard.

For example, near the mountains a staff can be used as a walking stick, but may not serve well physically (without magic) when climbing.  In a situation where it can help with climbing, such as by inserting it into a crack to build a handle that the wizard may pull against to lift himself up the mountain face, there is a risk it will get stuck.  If the wizard happens to be scaling the mountain secretly and cannot use magic, or must cloak the staff or wand from other magicians who may sense it's approach, then a physically stuck wand or staff is a good as a beacon if magic is needed to free it.  Likewise, being half way up a mountain, reaching for an handhold and receiving a shower of pebbles and dirt, even if the wizard can maintain his grip, if the staff is at hand in that situation it may be dropped and thus secrecy may preclude kinetic fetching of the object.

A similar argument can be posed for any kind of secretive approach.

#### Edit

Also, considering secrecy, if the staff or wand must be cloaked to avoid detection, then presumably this would also prevent the wizard from sensing his own connection to the object.  This would thereby make it possible for the object to become lost to the wizard by the effects of his own spell.

Comment: And security: you don't want to allow a cottage industry of muggers targeting wizards for their wands....Edit: now that I think about it, it sounds more like poaching

Answer (score 1):

Wands, in Harry Potter and beyond, serve wizards in a multitude of ways.

**Prevention of accidental magic**

So, in Harry Potter, young wizards have a capability of using magic without wands. My theory is that one of the reasons why wand magic is taught, is so that wizards don't strike out with magic accidentally. They are trained to the wand in order to train them out of using magic wandlessly because such a thing is dangerous & uncontrolled, both for the user and others.

**As a safe and efficient conduit/way to focus and amplify magic**

Magic might be in you, but wands do the job of focusing the power in ways that you might not be able to do otherwise. In other words, besides being more safe and controlled, you're also more powerful with a wand in your hand. Wands take the beating if something goes wrong, instead of, say, you.

**As a Familiar object**

In D&D there animal familiars boot stats for wizards and can help with magic in some ways. There are also alt rules regarding familiar objects, that, when broken, (just as when the animal kind are killed) take away those advantages. The animals in Harry Potter don't seem to work the way the D&D ones do, but the wands do seem to function in some ways like a familiar object.

**Spell Storage**

Speaking of D&D...most wands there have a particular spell stored inside them, ready to be released by the user. The magic has already been spent, perhaps during a quiet time in town when magic missile wasn't needed, but it only needs a magic user to release the spell.

Bottom line, however skilled a wizard is without a wand, it's more efficient and easier to use one. Like, I can open a package with my teeth, but I will use scissors instead, because they are a better tool than my teeth to do the job. In a pinch, I could do that, but why would I want to? Same goes for wizards and wands...